# Replace only first occurence of a character in filenames

Tags: powershell, file-rename, batch-rename

I have a folder with many files. What I want is to replace the first matching character of each file. For example I have

```
aabbc.txt
aaabbxx.txt
aacbbbv.txt
```

I want to replace the first "b" with a "z" the result will be

```
aazbc.txt
aaazbxx.txt
aaczbbv.txt
```

so only the first match will be replaced what I tried is

```
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace "b","a" }
```

but it replace all the "b" in the filename.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace '^(.*?)b', '$1z' }
```

The trick is to include the shortest match up to the first b (`(.*?)`) in the matching pattern and preserve it in the replacement by replacing it with itself (`$1`).